# I am getting a NullPointerException while I try to replace the word with the help of an array

Tags: java, error-handling, nullpointerexception

I am trying to work on a project and I am supposed to replace  '___' from one txt file with a missing word from another txt file. I have found the location of the missing word which is denoted by the pointer j. Now I am working on a function which will get the missing word from the file and put it in it's correct position. Unfortunately I am getting a NullPointerException error for some reason.

Here are the necessary global variables

```
public static char Missing_Word_Characters[] = new char[32];
public static char Underscore = '_';
```

Here's the part that finds the location of the missing word

```
while(i < Length_of_the_Script)
        {
            if(Current_Statement.charAt(j) == The_Truman_Show_Script.charAt(i))
            {
                i++; 
                j++; 

            }
            else if(Current_Statement.charAt(j) != The_Truman_Show_Script.charAt(i) && Current_Statement.charAt(j) == Underscore)
            {
                //Replace the underscores with the word
                System.out.println("There is a missing word at " + i); 
                Get_Word(); 
                New_Current_Statement = Current_Statement.replaceAll("___", Missing_Word);
                System.out.println(New_Current_Statement); 
                break; 
            }
```

Here is the function which get the missing word from the txt file character by character.

```
static void Get_Word()
    {
        int Word_Pointer = i;
        if(The_Truman_Show_Script.charAt(Word_Pointer) != WhiteSpace)
        {
            //get the character and increment Word_Pointer
            Missing_Word_Characters[Missing_Character] = The_Truman_Show_Script.charAt(Word_Pointer); 
            Missing_Character++;
            Word_Pointer++;     
        }
        else
        {
            Missing_Word = new String(Missing_Word_Characters); 

        }


    }
```

Here is the error message:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendExpandedReplacement(Matcher.java:1015)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:998)
>     at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:1182)
>     at java.base/java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2126)  at
>   Main.KMP_Algorithm(Main.java:77)  at Main.main(Main.java:51)

P.S. I am trying to convert an array of characters into a string and then use a function called replaceAll to replace the string with the underscores. Is that a good idea?

Your help would be much appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: It would be helpful to show the error message, especially which line of code caused it.

Comment: you have many unassigned variables in `Get_Word()` which we cannot see: `i` , `Missing_Character ` have you tried to debug? 
Most likely one of the arrays goes beyound it's boundaries

Comment: i and j are a global variable so I don't think I need to add parameters to the function.

Comment: what is value of `Missing_Word` variable? It might be that you were trying to replace `Current_Statement.replaceAll("___", Missing_Word);` with a `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `Missing_Word` is null. `Get_Word()` should return value which will be assigned to `Missing_Word` variable everytime an underscore is found.

```
Missing_Word = Get_Word(); 
New_Current_Statement = Current_Statement.replaceAll("___", Missing_Word);
```